# The value of my variable is changing In another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got this varible:

```
var things = $('#box li');
```

My problem is that the user can change the value in #box. So it contains x different li:s then my var things is not set anymore. How do I change this var? `var things` is in my `index.php` file. The place where the user changes the `#box` is in my `change.php` file, so I think It's a bit harder.

Probably I duplicate but I dont know what to search so please direct me if you can.

Comment: What is `#box`? You say users can change a value int it, meaning... it's an `<input>` field? That contains `<li>`?? Please edit your question and make a code snippet (there's a `[<>]` button for that) so we can see the relevant JS and HTML in action.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), which will return a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which you can select again:

```js
var things = $('#box')[0].getElementsByTagName("li")

console.log($(things).toArray())

$('li').last().remove() //remove last li element

console.log($(things).toArray())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @JeremyThille Didn't notice that, thanks! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Someone has deleted my comment, and I have no idea why